# Remove Content-Length header in nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I use nginx with proxy path directive.
When the application to which the request is proxied return a response, it seems nginx add some header containing the Content-Length. Is that possible to remove this additional header ?

**UPDATE**

I have re-installed nginx with the more_headers module but I still have the same result. My config is:

```
upstream my_sock {
   server unix:/tmp/test.sock
   fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
   listen 11111;
   client_max_body_size 4G;
   server_name localhost;

   keepalive_timeout 5;

   location / {
      more_clear_headers 'Content-Length';
      proxy_pass http://my_sock;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the ngx_headers_more module, then use more_clear_headers:

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#more_clear_headers

```
more_clear_headers 

syntax: more_clear_headers [-t <content-type list>]... [-s <status-code list>]... <new-header>... 

default: no 

context: http, server, location, location if 

phase: output filter
```

In your specific case you probably want to add:

```
more_clear_headers 'Content-Length';
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. I have updated my question with the nginx config. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This was due to the fact nginx talks to back ends in http 1.0
I needed to add the content-length in the response sent from the backend to avoid the encoding to be set to chunked.